# Fetching errors on a page with multiple forms in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 (although solutions for later versions are also okay).

I have a page, which contains BOTH the login page and registration page.

These forms use the `AuthController` as usual.

I display the errors like so:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="callout alert">
        <strong>Whoops! Something went wrong!</strong>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

The issue is, the `$errors` variable does not make it clear which form the errors come from (i.e. Is it errors in the registration form or login form?).

How can I do this?

Comment: Option 1 - check for the value of the errors to see where it's from. Option 2 - create ur own versions of $errors and work with those instead such as $registrationErrors and $loginErrors. Option 3 - do option 2 but all within the original $errors..... just some suggestions off the top of my head

Answer (score 1):

A way to handle this is to return flash messages. In your controller you can use something like:

For the login form

```
public function postLogin() {
    // your code here
    return redirect('/login')->with('login', 'Enter valid details');
}
```

For the sign up form

```
public function signUp() {
    // your code here
    return redirect('/login')->with('signup', 'SignUp has been successful');
}
```

And in order to display them in the view:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    @if(Session::has('login'))
        <div class="toast">
            {{ Session::get('login') }}
        </div>
    @endif              
</div>

<div class="clearfix">
    @if(Session::has('signup'))
        <div class="toast">
            {{ Session::get('signup') }}
        </div>
    @endif                  
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is how can I achieve this using Laravel's `AuthController`?

Comment: I believe you must have made two functions. One for login and the other one for signup? You can return the messages same way from there.